# Remove tomcat port number in the http URL

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, xampp, vhosts

I have a webapplication hosted on tomcat. I'm trying to achieve a URL redirection of my webappname. So, I'm using the vhosts config in apache of my xampp installation.

> My tools : Tomcat, XAMPP, APACHE

**Changes I made :**

```
In /System32/drivers/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 www.myapp.com
```

**Also, I requested for a domain name.**

```
nslookup myapp.com
Server: xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
Address:    xxx.xx.xxx.xxx#53

myapp.com   canonical name = blah-blah-myapp.com.
Name:   myapp.com
Address: xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
```

**In tomcat server.xml :**

```
     <Connector className="org.apache.catalina.connector.http.HttpConnector"
            connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"
            proxyName="www.myapp.com"
            proxyPort="80"/>
```

**In httpd.conf :**

```
LoadModule proxy_module  modules/mod_proxy.so
#AddModule  mod_proxy.c  # Gave error when tried to follow the docs

ProxyPass         /MyAppPath  http://localhost:8080/MyAppPath
ProxyPassReverse  /MyAppPath  http://localhost:8080/MyAppPath
```

**In http-vhosts.conf :**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName myapp.com
ServerAlias www.myapp.com
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /MyAppPath http://localhost:8080
ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080
```

By making these configurations, I achieved the functionality in my Macintosh machine. But, the problem is with windows server. I made the same changes in windows installation config files. It not skipping the PORT number. My app only works with the port number infront of the domain name. How can I make the `http request on port 80 to redirect to tomcat port 8080`

All I'm looking for is to implement something like www.myapp.com instead of localhost:8080/index.html. My app is running on port 8080. After the above config changes, i'm able to access the application with www.myapp.com:8080. I want to eliminate the 8080 from the url.

Comment: Do any URLs work on your Windows machine? If so, which ones? What URL(s) do you want to work, instead? Windows should allow you to launch Apache httpd listening on port 80 and therefore not require a port number (*after* the hostname, not before).

Comment: All I'm looking for is to implement something like www.myapp.com instead of localhost:8080/index.html. My app is running on port 8080. After the above config changes, i'm able to access the application with www.myapp.com:8080. I want to eliminate the 8080 from the url.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem

http://192.9.200.192:8080/myService/my/BaseService/base

OPEN

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\conf\sever.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

EDIT

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

open Configure tomcat from start menu if the service stop condition restart it (stop  -> start)

call URL like this

http://192.9.200.192/myService/my/BaseService/base

Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Your port numbers should be fine: Tomcat is listening on `8080` and Apache httpd is listening on `80`. If you want `http://www.myapp.com/` to go to your webapp, then you'll have to adjust your `ProxyPass` configuration:

```
ProxyPass /MyAppPath http://localhost:8080
ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080
```

That configuration is not valid, since `ProxyPassReverse` requires two arguments. I think you want something like this:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080
```

If you do the above, then everything will be proxied-over to Tomcat. (At this stage its worth asking yourself why you are bothering with Apache httpd *at all*, since everything is being proxied). You'll also want to set `proxyPort` to 80 in your `<Connector>` in `server.xml`.

If you want `/index.html` to work, and not show you the Tomcat "success" page that comes with it, then you need to re-name your webapp from `MyAppPath` to `ROOT` (case matters: it must be upper-case). Just re-name your webapp's directory to `ROOT` or your WAR file to `ROOT.war` and you should be good to go.

If you just want to use port 80 and don't need Apache httpd for anything else, then simply change Tomcat's `server.xml` so that your `<Connector>` for port 8080 is instead using port 80, and remove Apache httpd from the mix altogether.